# Can't change Brightness level on HP dv7-6179

Tags: 16.04, screen, brightness, hp

Im using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Before I could change the brightness with the key combination:

**"fn" + "f2" to decrease**

and

**"fn" + "f3" to increase**

But now, it only changes the bar in the right upper corner... but it doesn't affect the brightness of the screen...

I've tried creating the **"20-intel.conf"** file in

**/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d**

but when I logged in again, there was no change...

I've already tried with the **"Brightness controller"** and it **works**... but I would like to know if there is a way to "reset to defaults" those keys "fn" + etc... before reconfigure it with xbindkeys.

Comment: Is there anyone there who could help me with this? Is just to understand Ubuntu a little bit more. Thanks!

Comment: Anyone ? I have tried to look for this problem online and haven't found the solution.